# What exactly happens when you hit the IntelliJ "run" button?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

With IntelliJ you can use one of three build systems, *Ant*, *Maven*, and *Gradle*. Each of these systems defines a set of *tasks*, such as *build*, which it can execute.

Then there is the IntelliJ *run* button, shown in the image below:

[image]

One would expect that this button just executes the appropriate build system task. However this is **not** true.

I keep running into situations where I get a *completely* different behavior when running the project with the `gradle` command as when I run it with the `run` button.

I am currently using IntelliJ with gradle and the **spring-boot gradle plugin**, which defines a **bootRun task** which builds and runs the application. Sometimes the only way to start the application is to run it from the command line with an explicit `gradle bootRun` command. The IntelliJ run button causes the build process to fail because of some allegedly missing or unknown dependencies. Conversely, sometimes a misconfigured gradle project, that is not supposed to work and does not run from the command line, can be started by the IntelliJ run button. More disturbingly, some runtime bugs in my dependencies are only manifested with one or the other method.

I tried to go through the [IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html) but did not find the answer I was looking for.

I tried to dig into the "Edit Run Configurations":

[image]

Which did not help me much, other than telling me that before the launch IntelliJ would perform **build**. So I went out to see if I can figure out how this **build** is related to the `gradle build` task. In the general settings, one can find the configuration of the **build**, but it only supports what I already know, that is, it is not the same as using `gradle build`:

[image]

I am curious about what *exactly* this button does. To be more specific, what is the equivalent command-line command? Is there even such a command?

Comment: In addition try the spring-boot run config :-)

Comment: Adding to the linked question, you can run a JPS build from the command line, but it won't aid in understanding what exactly it does: you won't see any javac commands there. JPS interacts with the Java compiler through its API and does a lot of its own custom processing.